# Unity: The audio of a video file is choppy when played with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, video

I face a problem when playing some videos on unity editor or unity application (windows standalone application).
The audio of a video file is choppy.

If I play the recorded video file on Windows using any player the problem will not appear.

After working on this issue I think I figured out the problem: The duration of the audio of the recorded video is larger than the duration of the video it self.

You can see the details of a normal video and recorded video.

Normal video details:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qzKSr-Fb2ohb2W1xwooZum0xT3acQZM4/view?usp=sharing

Recorded video details: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jpr2IJwtIByLsWh7itVfm0nhoprarNm4/view?usp=sharing

My question is with 2 parts:

1- Can the difference in durations make this problem.

2- How to fix this problem in unity?

```
private IEnumerator PlayVideo(string filePath)
{
    //Add VideoPlayer to the GameObject
    _videoPlayer = gameObject.AddComponent<VideoPlayer>();

    //Add AudioSource
    _audioSource = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();

    //Disable Play on Awake for both Video and Audio
    _videoPlayer.playOnAwake = false;
    _audioSource.playOnAwake = false;
    _audioSource.Pause();

    //We want to play from video clip not from url

    //videoPlayer.source = VideoSource.VideoClip;

    // Vide clip from Url
    _videoPlayer.source = VideoSource.Url;
    _videoPlayer.url = filePath;


    //Set Audio Output to AudioSource
    _videoPlayer.audioOutputMode = VideoAudioOutputMode.AudioSource;

    //Assign the Audio from Video to AudioSource to be played
    _videoPlayer.controlledAudioTrackCount = 1;
    _videoPlayer.EnableAudioTrack(0, true);
    _videoPlayer.SetTargetAudioSource(0, _audioSource);

    //Set video To Play then prepare Audio to prevent Buffering
    //videoPlayer.clip = myVideoClip;
    _videoPlayer.Prepare();

    //Wait until video is prepared
    WaitForSeconds waitTime = new WaitForSeconds(1);
    _retryCount = 0;
    while (!_videoPlayer.isPrepared)
    {
        Debug.Log("Preparing Video");
        //Prepare/Wait for 15 sceonds only
        yield return waitTime;
        _retryCount++;
        if (_retryCount >= _maximumRetries)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    _vidFrameLength = (int)_videoPlayer.frameCount;
    ProgressBar.maxValue = _vidFrameLength;

    Debug.Log("Done Preparing Video");
    VideoPlayerImage.texture = _videoPlayer.texture;

    _videoPlayer.Play();
    _audioSource.Play();
    ClipLength.text = StringHelper.ToTime((float)_videoPlayer.frameCount / _videoPlayer.frameRate, TimePreviewer.Minutes);

    while (_videoPlayer.isPlaying)
    {
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm fearing this is less of a programming question and more of "how to manipulate audio files" type of query. Have you tried just making a copy of the sound file and truncating it to the same length as the video to test your theory?

Comment: There is no sound file. It is one video file (mp4 file) and the audio that I mentioned in the question is the sound or audio of the video file

Comment: Are you playing the video properly? Did you prepare the video? Did you wait for the prepare to be finished before playing it?

Comment: The player is playing other video files correctly. Even when playing this video the video is played perfectly.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it works for other videos and that didn't really answer the question. Did you prepare the video? Did you wait for the prepare to be finished before playing it?

Comment: Yes I prepare the video and wait for prepare to end

Comment: Ok. Please post the code in your question. That will help determine what you are doing wrong. Post the code that shows how you are playing the video.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using VideoPlayer component try to change
Audio Output Mode from AudioSource to Direct vise versa to see if that's change something.

Comment: If I change it to DIrect the video is played without sound

Answer (score 0):

For now, I found 2 video player libraries on Unity store that plays the choppy video without problems.

I am using one of them until Unity fixes the problem regarding playing variable frame rate videos.

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/video/ump-win-mac-linux-webgl-49625
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/video/avpro-video-windows-57969

I know this is not the solution for the question, but until anyone gives a good answer to the question I will use this.

Answer (score -1):

Try to modify the audiousource load type to "steaming" at the inspector.

Comment: 1- load type is for the audio clip, not for the audio source
2- It is a read-only property and can be only changed from the inspector (as you said). This can be done for audio clips and not for a video file.

Comment: Sorry ,my English is poor. I understood wrong with your question.